# Блокировка UI несмотря на асинхронность

Tags: c#, async-await

Создаю и запускаю задачу вот так:

```
var task = new Task(WorkWithResult, cts.Token); //cts.Token - маркер отмены, но это не важно
task.Start();
```

Переменные, которые используются в WorkWithResult:

```
var    result             = new int[N];
string stringResult = string.Empty;
```

Жду завершения задачи стандартно, вот так:

```
await task.ConfigureAwait(true);
```

WorkWithResult - локальная функция, выглядит вот так:

```
void WorkWithResult()
        {
            var sbResult = new StringBuilder(N * 5);
            var progressValue = 0.0;
            var progressStep  = 100d / N / 2;

            result[0] = PrimeNumbers.Next_prime(0);
            progress.Report((int) (progressValue += progressStep));

            for (var i = 0; i < result.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                result[i + 1] = PrimeNumbers.Next_prime(result[i]);
                cts.Token
                   .ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                progress.Report((int) (progressValue += progressStep));
            }

            foreach (var number in result)
            { // Блокировка UI. Почему?
                sbResult.AppendLine(number.ToString()); 
                cts.Token
                   .ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); 
                progress.Report((int) (progressValue += progressStep));
            }

            stringResult = sbResult.ToString();
        }
```

Во время выполнения последнего цикла происходит блокировка UI(массив чисел из 100 000, блокировка на 1 секунду). Почему? Код явно выполняется в другом потоке, я же запускаю его через `Task`. Все, чем отличается этот цикл от цикла 1 - это `sbResult.AppendLine`. 
Я подумал, что, возможно, дело в обращениях к массиву `result`, который создан не в том потоке, что выполняется `WorkWithResult`, но ведь блокировки не происходит в цикле 1.

Почему происходит блокировка, как ее избежать?

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что у вас в новом потоке все это бегает?

Comment: C того, что во время выполнения основной части функции интерфейс остается отзывчивым.

Comment: Но он же у вас по факту фризится, значит не отзывчивый)))

Comment: А если убрать `progress.Report`? Вангую, проблема в нём.

Comment: То есть вы 100 000 раз подряд отправляете репорт в UI и удивляетесь, что UI тормозит?

Comment: Обратите внимание,  я отправляю репорт не только в последнем цикле,  а еще и в первом. Но первый цикл не тормозит,  а второй тормозит. Утром попробую убрать Report,  напишу...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первом цикле вы отправляете отчеты с некоторой задержкой между ними (задержка обусловлена сложностью поиска простого числа). Вот в этот промежуток UI и успевает прорисоваться, отреагировать на действия пользователя и т.п.

Во втором цикле вы молотите новые репорты без остановки, ведь `AppendLine` работает очень быстро! (Даже быстрее чем отправка отчета) А потому поток UI занят исключительно обработкой отчетов и не успевает сделать ничего кроме обработки отчетов.

Из возможных исправлений самый простой способ - это убрать `progress.Report` из второго цикла.

Альтернативный вариант - отправлять каждый (N/50)й отчет, а остальные пропускать (если нужна точность до десятых долей процента - то каждый (N/500)й).

Еще один вариант - отслеживать время работы и отправлять отчет каждые полсекунды.

Comment: Ещё вариант — перейти на Rx и бороться с backpressure на клиентской стороне через какой-нибудь Throttle.